# Out of memory exception in blazor webassembly application

Tags: chromium, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I encountered the out of memory situation in blazor wasm (client-side) application, this is a weird situation as I am taking outmost care to de-allocate/release/dispose the memory (specifically byte array and memory streams) after its use, I understand that webassembly cannot release its memory to OS once allocate, It can only ask for the more memory this is by design of wasm VM. But can't we re-use the de-allocated address space for new data ? I tried various technique to achieve this including memory pooling but no luck (Using MemoryPool class from System.Buffers namespace). The memory of browser keeps on growing and eventualy browser crash. As per the chrome memory profiler the culprit is `system/JSArrayBufferData`. My question is how we can reuse the freed memory space for new data ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

 **EDIT**

Above issue can be reproduce with the below code

```
 @page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime;
<h1>Out of memory test.</h1>
<p role="status">Buffer collection count: @_collectionCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateBuffer">Create Buffer</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateBufferFromJs">Create Buffer From Js</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DestroyBuffer">Destroy Buffer</button>
@code {
    private int _collectionCount = 0;
    private List<BufferHolder> _bufferHolders = new List<BufferHolder>();
    private int _bufferLength = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    private int _iterations = 10;
    private async Task CreateBufferFromJs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] digits = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("CreateBuffer");
            _bufferHolders.Add(new BufferHolder(digits));
        }
        _collectionCount = _bufferHolders.Count;
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Buffer created.");
    }
    private async Task CreateBuffer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] digits = GetBytes();
            _bufferHolders.Add(new BufferHolder(digits));
        }
        _collectionCount = _bufferHolders.Count;
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Buffer created.");
    }
    private byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        byte[] digits = new byte[_bufferLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < _bufferLength; i++)
        {
            digits[i] = (byte)i;
        }
        return digits;
    }
    private async Task DestroyBuffer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _bufferHolders.Count; i++)
        {
            _bufferHolders[i] = null;
        }
        _bufferHolders.Clear();
        _collectionCount = _bufferHolders.Count;
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Buffer deleted.");
    }
    private record BufferHolder(byte[] Buffer);
}
```

And on Js side

```
function CreateBuffer()
        {
            var length = 5 * 1024 *1024 ;
            var arr = new Uint8Array(length);
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arr[i] = i;
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

In both ways i.e. creating buffer in C# or creation of buffer in JS side behaves the same.If you see the memory in task manager it keeps growing even after distroying the previous buffers before creating new ones.

Comment: The error is in your code and you posted none.  Set up a [mre]. Use File|New Project.

Comment: Yes, that's a good MRE now. I think this came up here before but I can't find it so quickly.

Comment: Did you solve this? @user2809953 We are experiencing similar issue with Blazor Wasm